# What's the difference between "bool" and "bool?"?

Tags: c#, boolean, nullable

I use the "bool" type for variables as I was used to in C++, and I try to put the values of functions or properties I expect to be boolean into my variable. However I often encounter cases where the result type is "bool?" and not "bool" and the implicit casting fails.

What is the difference between the two and when is each used? Also, should I use "bool?" as the type for my variable? Is this the best practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "DateTime?" mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c)

Comment: This does not seem to be a duplicate. This is a question that comes to mind. Just like me. Thanks

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `?` symbol after a type is only a shortcut to the [Nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx), `bool?` is equivalent to `Nullable<bool>`.

`bool` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), this means that it cannot be `null`, so the Nullable type basically allows you to wrap value types, and being able to assign `null` to them.

`bool?` can contain three different values: `true`, `false` and `null`.

Also, there are no short-circuiting operators (&& ||) defined for `bool?`

Only the logical AND, inclusive OR, operators are defined and they behave like this:

```
x        y      x & y   x | y   
true    true    true    true
true    false   false   true
true    null    null    true
false   true    false   true
false   false   false   false
false   null    false   null
null    true    null    true
null    false   false   null
null    null    null    null
```

The Nullable type is basically a generic struct, that has the following public properties:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T: struct
{
    public bool HasValue { get; }
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

The `HasValue` property indicates whether the current object has a value, and the `Value` property will get the current value of the object, or if HasValue is false, it will throw an InvalidOperationException.

Now you must be wondering something, Nullable is a struct, a value type that cannot be null, so why the following statement is valid?

```
int? a = null;
```

That example will compile into this:

```
.locals init (valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32> V_0)
IL_0000:  ldloca.s   V_0
IL_0002:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
```

A call to [initobj](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj%28VS.85%29.aspx), which initializes each field of the value type at a specified address to a null reference or a 0 of the appropriate primitive type.

That's it, what's happening here is the default [struct initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
int? a = null;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Nullable<int> a = new Nullable<int>();
```

Comment: Its a good answer but can I suggest that you make it clear that bool? is also a value type, its actually a structure which contains somethng like {T value; bool _hasValue}

Comment: And `!((bool?)null)` results in `null`.

Answer (score 18):

`bool?` is nullable while `bool` is not.

```
bool? first;
bool second;
```

In the above code, `first` will be `null` while `second` will be `false`.

One typical use is if you want to know whether there has been an assignment made to the variable. Since `bool` is a *value type* (just as `int`, `long`, `double`, `DateTime` and some other types), it will always be initialized to a default value (`false` in the case of a `bool`, `0` in the case of an `int`). This means that you can not easily know whether it's `false` because some code assigned `false` to it, or if it is `false` because it has not yet been assigned. In that case `bool?` comes in handy.

Comment: Note that those default values are only valid for instance/static variables, not local variables.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you see the ? character following a type name, it's shorthand for `Nullable<TypeName>`.  Nullable is a special type that allows value types to act like a null value.  It's a way of explicitly expressing a value type can have a non-value value.

For bool it effectively turns the variable into a tri-state value

- With Value: True
- With Value: False
- Without Value

Answer (score 5):

Adding `?` makes the type null-able. Which means you can do this:

```
bool? x = null;
```

And it would be totally OK.

Answer (score 4):

Another good place to use bool? is in a method to add null checking

```
public bool? IsTurkeyStillInFridge(Turkey turkey)
{
  if (turkey == null)
     return null;
  else if (fridge.Contains(turkey))
     return true;
  else
     return false;
}

bool? canStayAtDesk = IsTurkeyStillInFridge(turkey);

if (canStayAtDesk == null)
    MessageBox.Show("No turkey this year, check for ham.");
else if (canStayAtDesk == true)
    MessageBox.Show("Turkey for lunch. Stay at desk.");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Turkey's gone, go out to lunch.");
```

Answer (score 3):

bool? means the boolean is nullable and is syntactic sugar for a stucture `Nullable<bool>`. Because a boolean is a value type, you cannot set it to null, but there are some cases where you'd want to like in a data access class because database fields can have null values.

Answer (score 2):

`bool` can contain only `true` and `false` values while `bool?` can also have a `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

Means that the variable declared with (double?) is nullable

```cs
double i1=0.2; //ok
double i2=null; //not ok

double? i3=0.1; //ok
double? i4=null; //ok
```

Answer (score 0):

bool means you can have values of true and false. 
bool? means you can have a value of true, false, and null.

It works for datetime and booleans.