# What does double? mean in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# newbie: what’s the difference between “bool” and “bool?” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181491/c-newbie-whats-the-difference-between-bool-and-bool)

Hi, 
  While reading the code of the NUnit project's assert class, I came across this particular construct -

```
public static void AreEqual(double expected, double? actual, double delta)
{
     AssertDoublesAreEqual(expected, (double)actual, delta ,null, null);
}
```

In this function the second input parameter is entered as `double?`.
The interesting thing is that this code compiles without issue in VS2010 (C# 4.0). 
Anyone know why this is NOT throwing an error ? Why is `double?` considered a valid keyword and is there any special significance to the `?`.

Comment: See [C# newbie: what's the difference between "bool" and "bool?" ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181491/c-newbie-whats-the-difference-between-bool-and-bool)

Comment: Stop downvoting the guy, it's a valid question and it's hard for someone who doesn't know the nullable operator to find the answer. Just close the question as exact duplicate.

Comment: What's up with those downvotes? The question mark suffix isn't very search engine friendly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`double?` is just shorthand for `Nullable<double>`; basically, a `double` that can be `null`. But the code is not very safe. If `actual` is `null`, `(double)actual` will throw an exception.

Comment: +1 for warning for warning about the `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 7):

It's a nullable type. So it's a double that can also be null.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this means that the parameter could also be called null.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax T? is shorthand for System.Nullable.
Following line of code declares nullable type.

`double? actual =null;`

You can not assign null values to .NET value types (structs) including c# primitive types like int and double so in .NET 2.0 there is concept of nullable type is added to assign null value.

for example :

```
int? num = null;
        if (num.HasValue == true)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = Null");
        }
```