# Why is there a questionmark on the private variable definition?

Tags: c#, nullable

I am reading an article about the MVVP Pattern and how to implement it with WPF. In the source code there are multiple lines where I cannot figure out what the question marks in it stand for.

```
private DateTime? _value;
```

What does the `?` mean in the definition? I tried to find it in the help from VS but failed.

Comment: I removed the WPF tag, since it's not related to WPF...

Comment: Thank you for the many answers. Its bad that this was not in the indox of the msdn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "DateTime?" mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's a nullable value.  Structs, by default, cannot be nullable, they must have a value, so in C# 2.0, the `Nullable<T>` type was introduced to the .NET Framework.

C# implements the `Nullable<T>` type with a piece of syntactic sugar, which places a question mark after the type name, thus making the previously non-nullable type, nullable.

Answer (score 10):

That means the type is [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 9):

cannot be null

```
DateTime                        
DateTime dt = null;   // Error: Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime'
                         because it is a  non-nullable value type
```

can be  null

```
DateTime? / Nullable<DateTime>  
DateTime? dt = null;  // no problems
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a nullable type, you can assign null to it

Comment: More specifically it is a nullable value type.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the field is a `Nullable<DateTime>`, i.e. a `DateTime` that can be null

Answer (score 3):

Private DateTime? _value - means that the _value is nullable. check out this link for a better explanation.

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/05/23/1047.aspx

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Raja