# private int? _City_Id; can any one tell me what "?" means here

Tags: c#, types

private int? _City_Id;

Comment: what programming language is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326158/why-is-there-a-questionmark-on-the-private-variable-definition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing your target language to respond with, in [C# 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_2.0) the `?` denotes nullable value types.

> Nullable value types (denoted by a question mark, e.g. int? i = null;) which add null  to the set of allowed values for any value type.

Which, as Calum points out (*all credit to him*), means that the variable can be assigned `null`. Normally primitives like `int` and `double` can't be null,

```
int? x = 10;
double? d = 4.108
```

Comment: Which, in case that's not clear, means that the variable can be assigned "null". Normally primitives like "int" can't be null.