# what does symbol '?' after type name mean

Tags: c#

I am using [Eto gui framework](https://github.com/picoe/Eto). I saw some magic grammar in their source code;
for example:

```
int x;
int? x;
void func(int param);
void func(int? param);
```

What's different? I am confused.
and the symbol `?` is hard to google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a questionmark on the private variable definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326158/why-is-there-a-questionmark-on-the-private-variable-definition)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Basic question: What is '?'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699373/c-sharp-basic-question-what-is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`struct`s (like `int`, `long`, etc) cannot accept `null` by default. So, .NET provides a generic `struct` named `Nullable<T>` that the `T` type-param can be from any other `struct`s.

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct {}
```

It provides a `bool HasValue` property that indicates whether the current `Nullable<T>` object has a value; and a `T Value` property that gets the value of the current `Nullable<T>` value (if `HasValue == true`, otherwise it will throw an `InvalidOperationException`):

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct {
    public bool HasValue {
        get { /* true if has a value, otherwise false */ }
    }
    public T Value {
        get {
            if(!HasValue)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return /* returns the value */
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, in answer of your question, `TypeName?` is a shortcut of `Nullable<TypeName>`.

```
int? --> Nullable<int>
long? --> Nullable<long>
bool? --> Nullable<bool>
// and so on
```

and in usage:

```
int a = null; // exception. structs -value types- cannot be null
int? a = null; // no problem
```

For example, we have a `Table` class that generates HTML `<table>` tag in a method named `Write`. See:

```
public class Table {

    private readonly int? _width;

    public Table() {
        _width = null;
        // actually, we don't need to set _width to null
        // but to learning purposes we did.
    }

    public Table(int width) {
        _width = width;
    }

    public void Write(OurSampleHtmlWriter writer) {
        writer.Write("<table");
        // We have to check if our Nullable<T> variable has value, before using it:
        if(_width.HasValue)
            // if _width has value, we'll write it as a html attribute in table tag
            writer.WriteFormat(" style=\"width: {0}px;\">");
        else
            // otherwise, we just close the table tag
            writer.Write(">");
        writer.Write("</table>");
    }
}
```

Usage of the above class -just as an example- is something like these:

```
var output = new OurSampleHtmlWriter(); // this is NOT a real class, just an example

var table1 = new Table();
table1.Write(output);

var table2 = new Table(500);
table2.Write(output);
```

And we will have:

```
// output1: <table></table>
// output2: <table style="width: 500px;"></table>
```

Comment: +1 but ..`value types and will be stored in stack ...` - Not really. See: [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) By Eric Lippert

Answer (score 9):

It means they are [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), **they can hold null values**.

if you have defined:

```
int x;
```

then you can't do:

```
x = null; // this will be an error.
```

but if you have defined `x` as:

```
int? x;
```

then you can do:

```
x = null;
```

[`Nullable<T> Structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

> In C# and Visual Basic, you mark a **value type as nullable by using
>   the ? notation** after the value type. For example, int? in C# or
>   Integer? in Visual Basic declares an integer value type that can be
>   assigned null.

Personally I would use http://www.SymbolHound.com for searching with symbols, look at the result [here](http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=%3F++C%23)

`?` is just syntactic sugar, its equivalent to:

`int? x` is same as `Nullable<int> x`