# Variable type ending with ? 

Tags: c#, .net, types, nullable

What does `?` mean:

```
public bool? Verbose { get; set; }
```

When applied to `string?`, there is an error:

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Comment: Just to append to the other answers describing nullable types - a bool is stored in memory as a 0 or 1, there is no other option. By making it a nullable type allocates a larger area of memory where its value can be true,false or null. You'll notice that you can do things like Verbose.HasValue now which you couldn't do if it was defined as a bool.

Comment: Also to add to the general conversation, all reference types are nullable by default (I.E. you can set them all to null), so the Nullable<T> type is designed to not accept them, since it would duplicate functionality and complicate matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "DateTime?" mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`?` makes your non-nullable (value) types nullable. It doesn't work for `string`, as it is reference type and therefore nullable by default.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), about value types:

> Unlike reference types, a value type
>   cannot contain the null value.
>   However, the nullable types feature
>   does allow for values types to be
>   assigned to null.

`?` is basically a shorthand for [`Nullable<T> structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

If you want to know more, MSDN has a [great article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) regarding this topic.

Answer (score 11):

The `?` is shorthand for the struct below:

```
struct Nullable<T>
{
    public bool HasValue;
    public T Value;
}
```

You can use this struct directly, but the `?` is the shortcut syntax to make the resulting code much cleaner.  Rather than typing:

```
Nullable<int> x = new Nullable<int>(125);
```

Instead, you can write:

```
int? x = 125;
```

This doesn't work with string, as a string is a Reference type and not a Value type.

Answer (score 7):

`bool?` is a short form for `System.Nullable<bool>`. Only value types are accepted for the type parameter and not reference types (like e.g. string).

Answer (score 5):

`bool?` is a shorthand notation for `Nullable<bool>`. In general, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) states:

> The syntax T? is shorthand for
>   Nullable, where T is a value type.
>   The two forms are interchangeable

Since `string` is not a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws(VS.71).aspx) (it's a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2(VS.71).aspx)), you cannot use it as the generic parameter to `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

The ? operator indicates that the property is in fact a nullable type.

```
public bool? Verbose { get; set; }
```

is equilvalent to

```
public Nullable<bool> Verbose { get; set; }
```

A nullable type is a special type introduced in c# 2.0 which accepts a value type as a generic praramater type and allow nulls to be assigned to the type.

The nullable type only accept value types as generic arguments which is why you get a compile error when you try to use the ? operator in conjunction with the string type.

For more information:  [MSDN Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Only value types can be declared as Nullable. Reference types are bydefault nullable. So you cannot make nullable string since string is a reference type.

Answer (score 3):

the `?` means that your value type can have a null value, specially in the case of database

handling you need these nullables to check if some value is null or not.

It can be applied to only value types coz reference types can be null .