# Where in memory are nullable types stored?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

This is maybe a follow up to question about [nullable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863963/c-property-ending-with).

Where exactly are nullable value types (`int?`...) stored in memory? First I thought it's clear enough, as `Nullable<T>` is struct and those are value types. Then I found Jon Skeet's article "[Memory in .NET](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html)", which says:

> Note that a value type variable can
>   never have a value of null - it
>   wouldn't make any sense, as null is a
>   reference type concept, meaning "the
>   value of this reference type variable
>   isn't a reference to any object at
>   all".

I am little bit confused after reading this statement. So let's say I have `int? a = null;`. As `int` is normally a value type, is it stored somehow inside struct `Nullable<T>` in stack (I used "normally" because I don't know what happens with value type when it becomes nullable)? Or anything else happens here - perhaps in heap?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

First off, `Nullable<int>` is just a shorthand for something like:

```
struct Nullable<T> 
{
    bool hasValue;
    T value;
}
```

Plus all the constructors, accessors, and so on. That's all it is -- a nullable int is an ordinary int plus a flag that says whether the int is null or not. All the rest is compiler magic that treats "null" as a valid value; all "null" does with a nullable type is makes you one of those structs with the flag set to false.

So now that we have that out of the way, your question is "where do they go in memory"? They go the same place that any other structs go in memory: where the runtime and compiler believe to be the best place given the lifetime of the memory.

Most structs go on the heap. Anyone who tells you that "structs always go on the stack" doesn't actually know what they are talking about; our documentation does not say that and it is not true. Structs only go on the temporary memory pool, aka "the stack", when they are local variables or temporaries, and the local variables are not closed-over outer variables of an anonymous method or lambda, and the local variables are not in an iterator block.  All other structs go on the heap in our implementation.

Note also that there is no requirement whatsoever that an implementation of the CLI use "the stack" to make their temporary pool. The classic JScript memory manager, for example, stores its temporary pool on the heap. (Though of course the JScript runtime engine is not an implementation of the CLI; I'm merely pointing out that one can design a managed runtime engine that puts no user data whatsoever on "the stack".) Logically it is a stack data structure, but that data structure is not store on "the" stack, it's just a stack structure allocated on the heap.

I have to ask: why do you care? The CLR manages memory on your behalf. Why do you care where nullable types go? They go where they live long enough to be useful to you; you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: A very easy +1 from me. Thanks for exhausting answer. I care because I'm curious. I think (maybe naively enough) it's valuable information to know what actually happens behind my code. I don't want to end up coding something that does god-knows-what magic.

Comment: @Ondrej, if you think the Nullable compiler support is magic, try writing an IEnumerable method with yield returns using a lambda expression containing a closure.  Open up the resulting program in ildasm and take a look at what the compiler did for you under the covers.

Comment: I was speaking generally. Not that I actually think that everything in programming is a magic. I am aware that there are most likely more hard-to-understand pieces of code than this is.

Comment: a question to gain understanding should not be responded to with "why do you care?"

Comment: @wcpro: Of course it should. Understanding *why* a question is being asked is *absolutely key* to giving an answer that meets the actual needs of the questioner! If the questioner is asking out of curiosity, that's one thing. **If the questioner is going to be making a technical or business decision on the basis of the answer that is an entirely other thing**. It is very important to know why someone wants to know so that the answer can be tailored to give them the right information to make that decision effectively.

Comment: @EricLippert what about struct which has an object type field inside of it ? will it seat only also on stack ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You can answer this question yourself. `struct S { public object x; } ... S[] s = new S[10];` Does the variable `s[0].x` live on the stack or the heap?

Comment: @EricLippert I was talking about `S` itself not `x`. If I have a struct `S` and he has an `object` inside of it . where does this `S` will be ? ( in stack right ?). Also in your example since `S[]` is an array reference , the whole structure will be on Heap  , right ? (Thanks for answering...)

Comment: S will be wherever it needs to be to ensure the variable lives long enough.

Comment: Hi @EricLippert . Even after reading your answer i am not clear about why structs go on heap? Ain't this the very basic difference between a struct and a class? The basic value and reference type difference? Perhaps, you could point a documentation link that i could go through for more clarity

Comment: @hstg: Well, *think about it*.  You have an array of ints allocated by method `M` and returned. **Are the ints on the stack or the heap**? If they are on the stack then how were they not deallocated when M returned the array to its caller?

Comment: @hstg: The basic difference between value types and reference types is *reference types are passed by reference* and *value types are passed by value*.  That's why they're called reference types and value types.

Comment: @EricLippert The answer to your first comment is : Array is a reference type, so allocation of int array was done on heap. Automatic deallocation is done on the stack by GC and not on heap. 
Fully agree with your second comment and i do understand that not always will a value type go on stack. But i want to understand what scenario will that be? Not like an array of ints. Is there any instance in which an int value itself got stored on heap?

Comment: and please don't give example to the above question like class field member which obviously are stored on heap.

Comment: @hstg: You ask for examples of times that ints go on the heap but only want *not obvious* examples. I don't know what is obvious to you. But the question is the wrong question.  The question should be **when do variables go on the stack?** not **when do ints go on the heap** because **ints** aren't the thing that goes on the heap.  **Variables of any type** are what go on the heap or the stack.

Comment: @hstg: A variable of any type goes on the stack **when its lifetime is known by the compiler to be not longer than the activation of the method**. You have a variable of type int; if it's lifetime is longer than the method invocation, it goes on the long-term allocation pool.  Otherwise it goes on the short term pool.  You have a variable of type string, **same thing**.  Remember, the value of a variable of type string is a **reference to string** and **that thing** can go on the stack.  Think about **variables**, not their types.

Comment: @hstg: And now you can figure out for yourself when an int variable goes on the heap. Is it in an iterator block used on both sides of a yield? Then its lifetime is longer than the `MoveNext` invocation and it goes on the heap. Is an int in an `async` method and used on both sides of an `await`?  Then its lifetime is longer than the activation of the method and it goes on the heap. Is an int variable used in lambda that is converted to a delegate that is then passed out of the method? Then its lifetime is longer than the activation of the method and it goes on the heap. And so on.

Comment: Wow that makes it much more clearer, specially your middle comment. Just to sate my curiosity, is there any way in which a class can also get stored on stack?

Comment: @hstg: A *reference* to an object can certainly be stored on the stack. But can *the variables of the class itself*? Suppose we had `class C { int x; static void M() { C c = new C(); c.x = 123; }`.  There is a reference to a `C` in `c`, and that's on the stack, but what about `c.x`?  Since `c` does not escape `M` and no *alias* of `c` or `c.x` escapes `M`, the CLR could *in theory* put `c.x` on the stack.  **Theory and practice are different. In practice it never does this optimization**. This optimization is called "escape analysis"; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis.

Comment: @hstg: So now we see where the **myth** "value types go on the stack" comes from. The **truth** is: the fields of a value type go wherever the variable holding the value goes, and *that location is determined by the lifetime of the variable*. The fields of a reference type always go on the heap **because the CLR does not do escape analysis** and without escape analysis we cannot know if the fields are long-lived or not, so we assume they are.

Comment: @EricLippert "The basic difference between value types and reference types is reference types are passed by reference and value types are passed by value. That's why they're called reference types and value types."

Could you elaborate? 


"Unless you pass variables with the ref or out keywords, C# passes variables to methods by value, irrespective of whether the variable is a value type or a reference type." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606475/c-sharp-pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference

Also Jon Skeet: "If you want to use pass-by-reference, you must use out or ref"

Comment: @EricLippert I assume what you meant is something along the lines of "reference types are those in which the (value of the) reference is passed, and value types are those in which the value itself is passed"?

Comment: @RTF: That's correct, and I agree it was a little confusing the way I said it. The problem is that we have both the notion of a *reference to an object* and the notion of *an alias to a variable*, and we often use "pass by reference" to mean "make an alias to a variable".  I wish that the original design of C# had chosen something like `in_out` instead of `ref` for the "make an alias to a variable" keyword; it would have mitigated this point of confusion.

Answer (score 9):

See Eric's comment about where structs are stored.  It is much more thorough (and correct) than what I posted.

The way it works is that the nullable has a boolean that says whether or not the value has been set.  Technically you are correct the nullable (int, bool) etc isn't actually null.  it has a default value.  it's just that now the nullable type has a boolean you can check and see if that value was set or it is just it's default value.  The `=` and `==` are overridden to set the appropriate values when assigning `null` (and a value) to it

MSDN link to [Nullables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Another link describing how nullables work:
http://www.markzhou.com/blog/post/2010/01/27/Why-can-assign-e2809cnulle2809d-to-nullable-types.aspx

Comment: Structs are not always stored on the stack. A correct statement is "local variables of struct type which are not closed-over outer variables of an anonymous method or lambda expressions and are not in an iterator block are stored on the stack in the Microsoft implementation of the desktop CLR." There is no requirement that there be a data structure called "the stack" or that all structs be stored on it. Structs which are fields of a class or locals in an iterator block or outer variables are stored on the heap.

Answer (score 4):

Nullables only pretend to be null:

```
int? a = null;
Debug.Assert((a == null) == (!a.HasValue));
```

The compiler is complicit in this charade.  One funny consequence of this is the following:

```
Nullable<double> b = new Nullable<double>();
Debug.Assert(b == null); //I'm null upon construction!
```

They also get special boxing support:

```
int? c = null;
Object d = c;
Debug.Assert(d == null);
Debug.Assert(!c.HasValue);
```

Comment: You forgot the most magic of all (one you can't emulate with operator overloading): operator lifting.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kevin's answer: the compiler knows about Nullable types and changes an `==null` check into a call to ".HasValue".