# What is the most efficient way to reassign a struct?

Tags: c#

I have in my program a struct type called Square which is used to represent the location (int Rank, int File) of a square on a chess board.

If I assign Square by new Square sq(); say and then I want to reassign it, is it better to do so by

```
sq = new Square(rank, file);
```

or by writing an internal Set method and calling Set thus

```
sq.Set(rank, file);
```

What I am asking is when you use new on a struct, does the runtime reallocate new memory and call the constructor or does it reuse the existing memory? If it does the former then it would be better to write a Set method to avoid overheads would it not? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional thinking these days is the value types should be immutable, so you would not want to have a `Set` method *unless* that is returning a *new* `Square` object and not mutating the original. As such,

```
sq = new Square(rank, file);
```

And

```
sq = sq.GenerateSquare(rank, file); // renamed Set method from original question to appease comments
```

Should ultimately perform the same operation.

But given this approach, `GenerateSquare` would also possibly be better as a static method of `Square` rather than something depending upon any given instance. (An instance method would be more useful if something about the existing instance was used in the creation of a new instance.)

Comment: -1. Terrible coding practice. Any function with the name "Set" should never return anything. Use a name like "GenerateSquare" instead.

Comment: @Stargazer, that's fine. Keep in mind, I'm using *his* code and question as the base.

Comment: Yeah, I would have given you a point if you had simply left out the Set thing altogether and suggested the constructor approach only.

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, but you've changed how he's using it. If you change the action, change the name.

Comment: @Stargazer, noted. And I have.

Comment: I would then make GenerateSqaurea static method, kind of weird as an instance method.

Comment: @Ed Swangren, I agree and just made that same suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Switched to +1. Much better. Static would be good, factory class could be even better (assuming this structure is large enough to bother :) )

Comment: I guess I would like to mutate the original, for example sq changes as I iterate it through all the possible squares to which a chess piece can move.

Answer (score 2):

Structures are value types, so a simple assignment will do the job:

```
Square sq = new Square(rank, file);
Square anotherSq = sq;
```

Comment: Sometimes I don't have anotherSq, I just have the raw rank and file values.

Answer (score 1):

Worrying about the weight of garbage collection or memory use is something you should not be concerned with until you have profiled your application and know it will be an issue. A simple structure like this is not going be taking up much space and likely not the cause of problems if your program does hit a bottleneck.

Comment: +1. I agree with your assessment on the importance of worrying about this. If you are obsessed with memory management, don't use C# :)

Comment: Sorry, but`new` on a value type does _not_ allocate memory. Confusing, I know.

Comment: Confusing, indeed. Edited so it just has my real point about preemptive optimization.

Comment: Thank you Henk, that is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score -1):

For structs... space for new structs is created on the *stack*, (see NOTE),  not the *heap*, and is not subject to garbage collection.  If the assignment variable is an already existing copy of the struct, then it is overwritten.  No additional memory is used.

NOTE: If you create a new struct and assign it to a variable that is a property of a reference type, then yes, the reference type is on the heap, but the memory slot the struct is copied to is the *already existing* memory slot for that already existing reference type, *no new heap memory is allocated*. And the struct is *not* independantly subject to garbage collection....

But others' comments about your design are correct, structs should generally only be used for immutable domain objects, things that are simple and easy to create (small footprint) and have no identity (i.e., one telephone number object set to (802) 123-4567 is equivilent to and can be used anywhere else you need a telephone number object set to (802) 123-4567

So in general, these objects should not have constrcutors or property setters, they should have static factory methods that create instances of them.

Comment: @Henk, technically true, but only in exactly the same way as an int that is part of an object is on the heap... in either case, the struct (or the int) does not get it's own space on the heap (it gets the already allocated slot in the object it is part of... ) and it is still not subject to garbage collection (except indiretly when it's container gets collected)

Comment: Charles, the "value types are on the stack" sentence is repeated over and over (even on MSDN) but it is simply not true. And not useful. See this answer for a stronger statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865604/where-in-memory-are-stored-nullable-types/2866346#2866346

Comment: @Henk, I disagree.  It is critical to understanding the differences between value types and reference types, (except for boxed values) no value types are ever stored directly on the heap except as a constituent part of a reference type.  In fact, it could be argued that even then they are not "stored" on the heap, their value is inserted into the reference types slot for that field or property... But no value type ever gets Heap memory allocated for it, or explicitly affects the size or structure of the Heap...

Comment: @Henk your distinction is so ubiquitous that it is meaningless. You can alos place Unsafe pointers, file pointers, COM Objects, OS Handles, and just about anything else you can imagine, into properties of reference type.. They are all, therefore, on the Heap...?? No, such a distinction, that is so ubiquitosuly applicable, is, an effectively useful distinction at all.

Comment: Charles, stack and heap turn out to be 'implementation details'. The meaningful distinction between ref and value types is 'copy semantics'. It has been discussed to death, google with those terms. The link I gave you was just a random pick.

Comment: Henk, except that objects on the Heap are allocated dynamically, and are subject to garbage collection, the stuff on the stack is scoped to the stack frame of the method that the variable is declared in and is allocated when the methods stack frame is created, based on the method's internal state data requirements. I believe this is indeed important to understand...