# Nullable types in C# - Heap or Stack?

Tags: c#, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where in memory are stored nullable types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865604/where-in-memory-are-stored-nullable-types)

A very basic question on Nullable types - where do the nullable values get stored - Heap or Stack?

I would believe it should be stored in Stack as Nullable stack is a struct. How does Null value get stored in a stack?

Comment: Here is a link which might help you understand the Nullable types - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Comment: The important thing here is that you have an incorrect belief that value types go on the stack. Can you describe how you came by this incorrect belief?