# What is the difference between float and float? return type in C# property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “DateTime?” mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c)

Hi All,
I recently came across with some code in C# where float? is used as return type. I want to know what is the concept behind using this and in which scenario we need to use it against normal float return type.

Thanks

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of [What does "DateTime?" mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c) (just substitute `DateTime` in that article for `float`).

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate is it? If you know what `DateTime?` and `Float?` mean then yes, it is the same question, but if you don't know the answer to the question, then they may well be completely different questions.

Answer (score 2):

float? means Nullable<float>. Basically it is a wrapper for value types. By using it you are able to assign null to variable, which is not possible when it comes to value types.

Answer (score 1):

float? is nullable

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx