# Difference "decimal" and "decimal?" types, when to use either of them

Tags: c#, nullable

Can anyone help me in understanding to know the difference between `decimal` and `decimal?` or `int` and `int?`?.

When should I use them and what are the positives of using either of them.

Comment: Take a look at this [Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "DateTime?" mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**data types with ? are nullable types. They can hold null value as well**
Check out this [Source link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mosessaur/nullabletypes08222006164135PM/nullabletypes.aspx)

> - Nullable types represent value-type variables that can be assigned    the value of null. You cannot create a nullable type based on a
>     reference type. (Reference types already support the null value.)
> - The syntax T? (in C#) is shorthand for System.Nullable, where T is    a value type. The two forms are interchangeable.
> - Assign a value to a nullable type in the same way as for an ordinary     value type, for example:
>           C#: `int? x = 10; or double? d = 4.108;`
>
>   VB.NET: `Dim x As Nullable(Of Integer) = 10` or `Dim d As    Nullable(Of Double) = 4.108`
> - Use the System.Nullable.GetValueOrDefault method to return either the    assigned value, or the default value for the underlying type if
>     the    value is null, for example
>
>   C#: int j = x.GetValueOrDefault();
>
>   VB.NET: `Dim j as Integer = x.GetValueOrDefault()`
> - Use the HasValue and Value read-only properties to test for null and    retrieve the value.
> - The HasValue property returns true if the variable contains a value,    or false if it is null.
> - The Value property returns a value if one is assigned, otherwise a    System.InvalidOperationException is thrown.
> - The default value for a nullable type variable sets HasValue to    false. The Value is undefined.
>     **In C# 4.0**
> - Use the ?? (C#) operator to assign a default value that will be    applied when a nullable type whose current value is null is assigned
>     to a non-nullable type, for example

```
int? x = null; 
int y = x ?? -1;
```

Answer (score 6):

The `?` after the type is describing that it is nullable. `int?` and `decimal?` are short-hand for `Nullable<int>` and `Nullable<decimal>`.

This allows the variable to hold its type or a null value.

Answer (score 1):

The ? form just means it's a nullable value type. It's a shortcut for `Nullable<decimal>` or `Nullable<int>`. A good time to use it would be when you want to be able to indicate that there is no value assigned to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

One use-case is if you have things like a `DateTime` and you want to indicate that you haven't assigned a value to it yet. Rather than set it to a "Magic date" like 01/01/1970, you can set it to null. Much more straightforward!