# What does the ? operator mean in C# after a type declaration?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have some C# code with the following array declaration. Note the single `?` after `Color`.

```
private Color?[,] scratch;
```

In my investigating I have found that if you you have code such as:

```
int? a;
```

The variable `a` is not initialized. When and where would you use this?

Comment: If you were doing some mathematic calculations based upon a users input, you would want to make sure that they have entered a number so that the equation doesn't use the default value

Comment: How did you add `nullable` tag beside you don't know what is `?` mean?

Comment: I'm always amazed to see, that when the question is simple, there are lots of duplicate answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "DateTime?" mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`?` is just syntactic sugar, it means that the field is Nullable. It is actually short for [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

> In C# and Visual Basic, you mark a value type as nullable by using the
>   ? notation after the value type. For example, int? in C# or Integer?
>   in Visual Basic declares an integer value type that can be assigned
>   null.

You can't assign `null` to value types, `int` being a value type can't hold `null` value, `int?` on the other hand can store null value.

Same is the case with `Color`, since it is a structure *(thus value type)* and it can't hold null values, with `Color?[,]` you are making an array of nullable Color.

For your question:

> The variable 'a' is not initialized. When and where would you use
>   this?

By using `?` with variable doesn't make it initialized with `null` or any other value, it is still has to be initialized.

```
int? a = null; 

int b = null;//error since b is not nullable
```

Comment: What about in a statement.  client?.Close(); ?

Comment: If it’s merely syntactic sugar, how are `?` and `Nullable<T>` interchangeable?

Comment: @dakab, at compile time they change, for example, `int?` will become `Nullable<int>`

Answer (score 4):

It means that the type defined is nullable. Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info.

With nullables you can do:

```
int? i = null;
```

And of course do null checks:

```
if (i == null)
{
    // do stuff here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the object can have a `null`-value in Addition to their normal range.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Nullable types are instances of the Nullable struct. A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value. For example, a Nullable, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null value.
>   ...

Example

```
class NullableExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int? num = null;

        // Is the HasValue property true? 
        if (num.HasValue)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = Null");
        }

        // y is set to zero 
        int y = num.GetValueOrDefault();

        // num.Value throws an InvalidOperationException if num.HasValue is false 
        try
        {
            y = num.Value;
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Color?` refers to a [`Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) `Color` and is equivalent to  `Nullable<Color>`.

```
Color c = null;//ERROR Color is a struct, cannot be null!
Color? c = null;//OK
```

[Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> The syntax T? is shorthand for System.Nullable, where T is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its a Nullable Structure

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Also a duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407552/what-does-question-mark-after-a-type-name-mean-in-c

Comment: You cannot search questions with just '?'. That is why there is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The ? operator signifies that the value type immediately preceding the operator may have the value null.

One way to think of it, and by no means a formal definition, is its an "exception" to how the value would "normally" be assigned a value.

A classic use case of the operator is in a simple controller in a web app. Suppose we have a typical DB that stores a list of movies. We can access the details of these movies by adding into the URL the following:

```
.../Movies/Details?MovieName=TopGun
```

, or,

```
.../Movies/Details?MovieName=DieHard
```

But what if we wanted to see the details of a movie where the value of MovieName is not defined? What will you show on your HTML page? Well, this controller will notify us of a bad request:

Check this out:

```
// GET: Movies/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```