# How does Entity Framework Core decide which properties are going to be NOT NULL in the database?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework to create a simple banking application for learning purposes. I don't understand how it decides which properties will become nullable and which become non nullable columns in the database.

For example this

## model

```cs
public class Transaction
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Account From { get; set; }
        public Account To { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public String Currency { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

generates the following

## SQL

[image]

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] (
    [Id]        INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Amount]    DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Currency]  NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [FromId]    INT             NULL,
    [Timestamp] DATETIME2 (7)   NOT NULL,
    [ToId]      INT             NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Accounts_FromId] FOREIGN KEY ([FromId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Accounts_ToId] FOREIGN KEY ([ToId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts] ([Id])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Transactions_FromId]
    ON [dbo].[Transactions]([FromId] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Transactions_ToId]
    ON [dbo].[Transactions]([ToId] ASC);
```

## Question

**Why is `Currency` nullable but not `Amount`? And what about the foreign keys `FromId` and `ToId`?**

## Appendix

In case it is relevant, here is the `Account` class referenced by the `Transaction` class.

```cs
public class Account
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }    
        public User User { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("From")]
        public ICollection<Transaction> TransactionsSend { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("To")]
        public ICollection<Transaction> TransactionsReceived { get; set; }

        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "DateTime?" mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of conventions at work here. You can fine-tune everything but the basic rules are clear and simple:

> Why is Currency nullable but not Amount? And what about the foreign keys FromId and ToId?

Amount is a value-type. The C# property can't be `null`  When you change it to `decimal?` the column will be nullable too.
Currency is a reference-type (string ). The From and To properties are references too. References will map to ALLOW-NULL unless you mark them as `[Required]`

And DateTime is also a value-type.

Comment: And what about Timestamp of type `DateTime`? Isn't it a reference type as well? It is nullable nonetheless.